# Is it a wise decision to take up full time role of Scrum Master?

Tags: career-switch

I'm working as a Java application developer for the past 7 years. I do nothing great. Haven't worked on core concepts such as multi-threading. And haven't worked on frameworks like Spring, Hibernate, etc., Because of which I'm usually shoed away from interview pretty quick.

Recently, I've been given an option to either take up full time Scrum Master role (as I have a little experience being one) or to take up a full time Python developer role. I'm in dilemma. I know my future if I choose to be a developer. I want to know the pros and cons of being a full time Scrum Master, far from writing code.

Anyone here that can help?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: I can't answer the question so I'll just tell you this: There is no such thing as a full time Scrum Master (Well if there is, then they're not understanding it correctly). There is no such thing as a _full time Agile role X_ anything... The agile roles are _shared among the developers_. The Scrum Master is suppose to be a member of the development team who spends some Y time making sure that everything is going the way it should be going in terms of Agile. It's really just an add on to the development role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've been a Scrum master then you should be able to see the pros and cons.  The question I'd ask is where do your passions lie?

A good Scrum master is constantly dealing with people, but with (usually) a technical hat on, to ensure estimates and commitments are feasible, and to get involved in negotiating when things prove more tricky.

Is this what you want to do, or (as it sounds to me) you are thinking about it as your not sure of your coding ability?  A Scrum master can make or break a team (I've been doing it for 10 years).  If you are just unsure of your coding, get some training, or maybe try a move into a new field (like the Python role).

Are you prepared to take responsibility for the whole teams performance, or just your own?

Comment: I would like to believe that I'm a good programmer.  It's just that the current and past roles did not involve up-to-date frameworks.  I can learn frameworks in few days however, employers expect us to have hands-on experience. This is driving me to consider Scrum Master role. I have experience as part time scrum master which is limited to driving the usual ceremonies, and not estimations, metrics, negotiations, etc.,

Python developer role does sound easy to pick up because I have been a Java developer for 7 years now. However,I feel there wouldn't be much of a vertical growth as a developer.

Comment: yeah, but ceremonies is the easy bit, I can give you nice pocket guides that tell you just how to do these, it's the other stuff that's key.  Planning timeboxes (and negotiating with the Product Owner), keeping flow, recognising things going askew in the standups and asking the hard questions, and dealing with the business when things go wrong are where you make a difference as a SM, the ceremonies can be done by the team themselves

Comment: You're right. I feel this is a risk to change role with the change of company. I shall consider the developer role and probably switch to SM role later.  Thank you for the suggestion.  Can you also let me know how is the trend of demand for SM in the market?

Comment: Depends on where you mean.  In the UK, 4 years ago I was unusual as I did Agile, and had to explain it.  Now most companies want it, so being a Scrum master is a good career (although you're usually jostling with former PMs who think this is just the Agile name for a PM). On the Python side, most of the people I know using it are investment banks, and it's usually tied in with NOSQL skills, so learn that and you'll get something good.  As regards no-experience, learn the framework/language, write some good code, publish on Github, use that in job interviews, a lot are using this as a cv now.

Comment: Thing is for developers, what I look for is guys who are so interested that they learn these things in their own time, and WANT a job to be able to do real things, saying you've not been able to use something due to project requirements doesn't cut it anymore.  The technology moves so fast, you need to be passionate enough to do your own thing.  Even I as a Dev manager and SM has this week been doing continuous intergration/delivery from Git to Azure so I can know where the pain points are when my team start doing it in a couple of timeboxes.

Comment: I totally agree with your opinion.  Thank you so much!